# Find the limit of f(x,y)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2},$$ determine the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.
The answer for this would be $0$ right??

and can it be calculated from:

$$f(x,0) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}= 0$$ and

$$f(0,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}= 0$$ ??

Comment: I am sure that this **is** a duplicate of something, but would the dupe voters please find a more appropriate target. @LordSharktheUnknown may be you missed that in the current dupe target $(x,y)\to(2,1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question you can use the polar coordinates to calculate the limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} f(x,y) = \lim_{r\rightarrow0} f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{r^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2}=r\cos\theta\sin^2\theta=0$$
since $\cos\theta\sin^2\theta$ is bounded and $r\rightarrow0$.